# ng-switch with typeof expression

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-switch

So I have a variable which could be of any type. By type I mean it could be a string, or an object. I'm trying to run different code depending on the type.

My variable is named `range`, it's defined in the JavaScript. What I've tried is. `vars` is an object which I'm looping through.

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, range) in vars">
    <td ng-switch="typeof range">
        <span ng-switch-when="string">It's a string</span>
        <span ng-switch-when="object">It's an object</span>
        <span ng-switch-default>It's something else</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

but this will throw an invalid expression error. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: In Controller `$scope.type = typeof $scope.range;` and in view `<td ng-switch="type">`. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @Tushar problem is this is in an ng-repeat so I don't think I can do that. Let me clarify

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this...  I also added detection for different types of variables: `string`, `array`, `object`, `number`, `null`, and `undefined`.

```js
"use strict";
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller("myController", function() {
    this.vars = {
        key1: "String",
        key2: "String2",
        key3: 42,
        key4: {
            name: "Mr. Anderson"
        },
        key5: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        key6: null,
        key7: undefined
    };
    this.getTypeOf = function(value) {
        if(value === null) {
            return "null";
        }
        if(Array.isArray(value)) {
            return "array";
        }
        return typeof value; 
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, range) in ctrl.vars">
        <td ng-switch="ctrl.getTypeOf(range)">
            <div ng-switch-when="string">It's a string</div>
            <div ng-switch-when="object">It's an object</div>
            <div ng-switch-when="number">It's a number</div>
            <div ng-switch-when="array">It's an array</div>
            <div ng-switch-when="null">It's null</div>
            <div ng-switch-when="undefined">It's undefined</div>
            <div ng-switch-default>It's something else</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Controller:

```
$scope.checkType = function(obj){    
 return typeof obj;
};
```

Html:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="(key, range) in vars"
        <td ng-switch="checkType(range)">
            <span ng-switch-when="string">It's a string</span>
            <span ng-switch-when="object">It's an object</span>
            <span ng-switch-default>It's something else</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
```